# How to add dynamic columns in sql for the below requirement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which looks like below. It has four standard columns `id, odn_no, acc , Item` out of which `Item` is `Listagg` function based field which has values separated by a delimiter pipe. This can have any no. of values appended by pipe. Below is the query and sample results

```
SELECT n.id, n.odn_no, n.acc, 
   Listagg('Item ID:'|| (SELECT value FROM   partner WHERE  col1 = 'ABC' )   
          ,'|') within GROUP( ORDER BY n.id, n.odn_no, n.acc ) AS Item 
FROM main_table n 
GROUP  BY n.id, n.odn_no, n.acc
```

produces results like below

[image] 
    
Now i would need to change the last column Item which was a `listagg` value earlier. Now I have to split the column Item to `Item1` `Item2` `Item3` and so on depending on the results that is produced by the `Listagg`.

For suppose if a row has 10 values separated by the delimiter `'|'` for the column `Item`, then the Headers of the result should have `Item1`, `Item2` , `Item3` ... `Item10`.

If a record has only 2 values for this field then it should come under
`Item1`, `Item2` and remaining will be empty. i.e.,  for the above results, I should show like below.

[image]

Please help me how to achieve this in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL. I have tried doing with a temp table by calculating the no. of max columns that a row can produce and depending on that create a temp table but not getting exactly how to create and insert the data. Looking forward for the help. Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with cur (id, odN_no, acc, item) as
  2    -- result of your current query; you'd put your own SELECT in here
  3    (select 1, 'odn1', 'ac1', 'p1|p2' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'odn2', 'ac2', 'p2|p3|p4' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'odn4', 'ac3', 'p6|p7|p8|p9|p5|p13|p14' from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    -- split previously concatenated ITEM values into rows
  9    (select
 10       id, odn_no, acc,
 11       regexp_substr(item, '[^|]+', 1, column_value) val,
 12       column_value cv
 13     from cur cross join
 14       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 15                           connect by level <= regexp_count(item, '\|') + 1
 16                          ) as sys.odcivarchar2list))
 17    )
 18  -- final result; conditionally aggregate values
 19  select id, odn_no, acc,
 20    max(case when cv = 1 then val end) item1,
 21    max(case when cv = 2 then val end) item2,
 22    max(case when cv = 3 then val end) item3,
 23    max(case when cv = 4 then val end) item4,
 24    max(case when cv = 5 then val end) item5,
 25    max(case when cv = 6 then val end) item6,
 26    max(case when cv = 7 then val end) item7
 27  from temp
 28  group by id, odn_no, acc
 29  order by id;

        ID ODN_ ACC ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM5 ITEM6 ITEM7
---------- ---- --- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
         1 odn1 ac1 p1    p2
         2 odn2 ac2 p2    p3    p4
         3 odn4 ac3 p6    p7    p8    p9    p5    p13   p14

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but in the final select statement, you have considered fixed no. of columns as 7  for Item (item7), but for my requirement,  it should be dynamic and may vary from 1 to any.

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment. For dynamic number of columns, SQL maybe isn't the best choice. Consider using a reporting tool (such as Oracle Reports Builder) which allows you to create matrix reports **easily**.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic columns are usually best handled by an application or through a procedure that returns a dynamic ref cursor. But if your solution must be done in a single SQL statement, then you'll need something like my open source project [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4).

After installing the code, you can dynamically pivot results by passing a query where the column names are pulled from the second to last column and the values are pulled from the last column. (The default aggregate function is `MAX`, but you can override that by passing a second parameter to the function.)

For example, with a sample table like this:

```
--drop table main_table;
create table main_table(id number, odn_no varchar2(100), acc varchar2(100), item varchar2(100), value varchar2(100));

insert into main_table
select 1, 'odn1', 'acc1', 'item1', 'p1' from dual union all
select 1, 'odn1', 'acc1', 'item2', 'p2' from dual union all
select 2, 'odn2', 'acc2', 'item1', 'p2' from dual union all
select 2, 'odn2', 'acc2', 'item2', 'p3' from dual union all
select 2, 'odn2', 'acc2', 'item3', 'p4' from dual union all
select 3, 'odn4', 'acc3', 'item1', 'p6' from dual union all
select 3, 'odn4', 'acc3', 'item2', 'p7' from dual union all
select 3, 'odn4', 'acc3', 'item3', 'p8' from dual union all
select 3, 'odn4', 'acc3', 'item4', 'p9' from dual union all
select 3, 'odn4', 'acc3', 'item5', 'p5' from dual union all
select 3, 'odn4', 'acc3', 'item6', 'p13' from dual union all
select 3, 'odn4', 'acc3', 'item7', 'p14' from dual;

commit;
```

Your query would be this simple:

```
select * from table(method4.pivot('select * from main_table'));

ID  ODN_NO  ACC   item1  item2  item3  item4  item5  item6  item7
--  ------  ----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
 1  odn1    acc1  p1     p2               
 2  odn2    acc2  p2     p3     p4            
 3  odn4    acc3  p6     p7     p8     p9     p5     p13     p14
```

I think your real query needs a join to the `PARTNER` table, but it's not clear to me how that join would work. But the advantage of this technique is that you can keep the joining simple and let the function handle the aggregation.